# Laravel ошибка про имэйл

Tags: php, html, laravel

сама ошибка

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'rickeyfsimple@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `name`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values...

```
   create_users_table.php
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username',255)->unique();
            $table->string('email',255)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\User; 


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

        $newUser = new User;

        $newUser->email = $user->getEmail();

        $newUser->name = $user->getName();

        $newUser->password = bcrypt(123456);

        $newUser->save();

        return redirect('home');


    }


}
```

web.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::get('login/google', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');

Route::get('login/google/callback',
'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: Поле `email` уникальное, Вы пытаетесь добавить пользователя с email адресом, который уже есть в ваше бд

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'rickeyfsimple@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique'` - эта ошибка Вам действительно ничего не сказала, что Вы решили задать этот вопрос на SO? Перед тем, как опубликовать вопрос, попробуйте прогуглить сначала вдумчиво прочитать ошибку, потом её прогуглить, а уже потом идти на SO, если ответ не найден. Сэкономите и свое, и чужое время :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в таблице `users` установлено ограничение уникальности поля `email`. Раз возникает такая ошибка, то значит в таблице уже есть запись с `email = rickeyfsimple@gmail.com`.

Comment: я начинающий в ларавел, можете показать это в коде

Comment: Да тут не Lavarel, а просто работа с бд. у вас уже существует запись с таким email, а вы пытаетесь добавить еще одну. замените email или уберите это ограничение, если оно излишне